# Uploading image using json in aps mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function for uploading selected files into folder in asp mvc4. The code in view page is

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="EmployeeDetails/Upload">
<input type='file' id="imgInp" accept="image/jpeg"/>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

And the controller code is

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase imgInp)
        {
            if (imgInp != null && imgInp.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(imgInp.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Profile"), fileName);
                imgInp.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return view("Index");
        }
```

Instead of this i want to send the image from view to controller as Json. Or is there any other methods to upload image without refreshing the view page..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send form using ajax...

```
<form id="login-form">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="files" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
    <button type="submit" onclick="submitform()">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

jquery

```
function submitform(){
        var postdata = $('#login-form').serialize();          
        var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("files", file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/Home/Index", false);
        xhr.send(fd);    
    }
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(FormCollection data)
    {

      if (Request.Files["files"] != null)
        {
          using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["files"].InputStream))
           {
             var   Imagefile = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);//your image
           }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Got it. Will it work if there is other contents in the form. I want to display the uploaded image in the form itself.

Comment: yes it will work...you can send entire form..just get append your data in `FormData` it will work

Comment: Can i change the file name before uploading and how can i specify a particular path for uploading ?

Answer (score 2):

uploading file to the server is quite simple. we need is a html form having encoding type set to multipart/form-data and a file input control.

View: NewProduct.cshtml

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Product</legend>
    <div>
                <label>Product Name:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductName)
    </div>
    <div>
                <label>Product Image:</label>
               <input name="photo" id="photo" type="file">
    </div>
    <div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The uploaded files are available in HttpFileCollectionBase of Request.Files.

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewProduct()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files["photo"];
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                  string subPath = Server.MapPath("ProductLogo");
                  bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath);
                  if (!isExists)
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
                  var path = Path.Combine(subPath+"\\", fileName);
                  if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                  {
                      var nfile = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "_" + fileName;
                      path = Path.Combine(subPath+"\\", nfile);

                  }
                  file.SaveAs(path);
                  return RedirectToAction("List", "Product");
                }
                else
                {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please Select an image");
                   return View();
                }
           }
          else
          {         
             return View();
          }  
      }
```

Comment: This is not utilizing JSON, as the OP requested... it's just a standard file post.